# Selenium WebDriver Find nth element

Tags: xpath, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am kinda stuck in a problem and am not able to fix it I have to access nth image on my page which comes in table inside HTML. I need to click on image to move to next screen respectively for each row

I have tried various solution provided here but since I am working with findElement(by) syntax I am not able to run my code with those assistances

My code is:

```
public void editUser(String userName)
{
    System.out.println("in editUser 1");
    int row = getCellRow(table, userName);
    System.out.println("in editUser 2");

    WebElement  edit = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='grid']/tbody/tr[2]/td[8]/a[1]/img"));

    System.out.println("in editUser 3");
    edit.click();
    System.out.println("in editUser 4");
    clickButton(closeButton);
}
```

Error is :

```
No such element exception. Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath", selector"://img[@title='User Management'])[2]
```

Selenium IDE could recognize my element but not selenium web driver !
Please advice

Comment: Post your html code snippet here.

Comment: Give us an example of what you are trying to find.

Comment: Santoshsarma: I have added html code snippet here . Please see and sdvice

Comment: Arran: I have a table with rows. Each row have various columns and one of the column is an image which takes user to next page when clicked. But i am unable to click on that image :(                                  Please have a look at java and html code and advice

Comment: <table align="center" width="95%" border="0" class="grid"> <tr class="odd"> .<td style="color:green">Success</td>
<td> Yes
<td align="right" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap">      
<a href="javascript:openUserManagementDialog(2);"><img align="top" width="17" border="0" height="17" title="User Management" src="./images/edit_pencil.gif" style="background-color: transparent;"></a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:openDeleteConfirmDialog(2,false);"><img align="top" width="17" border="0" height="17" title="Delete User" src="./images/Delete.png"></a>
</td>

Comment: tried below code as well but that too does not work with web driver:  //xpath("//img[@title='User Management'])[" + row + "]" ;

Comment: Tried new xpath which is working with IDE when i tested but failed to work in selenium Web driver code :(                                                     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='grid']/tbody/tr[4]/td[9]/a[1]/img")).click();

Answer (score 8):

Use [ ] to reference the nth element for instance

```
WebElement  edit = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@class='grid']//img)[n]"));
```

Where n is the element number

Comment: Does anything look wrong with this locator? I am receiving an unexpected timeout using WebDriverWait. `locator = (By.XPATH, '(.//input[@type=text])[1])'`)

Answer (score 2):

Since the html snippet is not a complete view, its unable to advice if the xpath used is right. With what is presented here, could suggest the following to move forward

1. Try using xpather (firefox plugin) to check if the xpath used
   returns the right image you are trying to click.
2. If above condition passes, then there could be timing issues for the image to load
   before webdriver tries to find it.