# Getting the first 5 links of a Google search

Tags: c#, selenium, search, hyperlink

I'd like to make a simple console application, similar to a search engine.

It asks the user what to search, finds results on google, and then the user can type "Click on the first/second/third link(etc)" and the application automatically clicks on that link.

I've tried using Selenium and I got to the point where I could initiate the search and find the results, but I didn't know how to actually *click* on a link. I've also tried using mouse coordinates, but the code is too complicated for me.

I've also tried to find a way to *extract* the links of the first 5 google results and THEN by some way click them.

Anyway, I've been searching for hours, but I haven't found anything yet. It would be amazing if you guys could help me out!

Here's the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Search for:");
    string command = Console.ReadLine();
    IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
    driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

    IWebElement searchInput = driver.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib"));
    searchInput.SendKeys(command);
    searchInput.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
}
```

Comment: Gotta be more specific in your questions.

Comment: If you actually look at the links in Google results, the hrefs are not a URL you would recognize.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Selenium (might be good to tag your question with [tag:selenium] if that's what it's about), but this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14372673/945456. It would also probably be helpful to show us what you do have working so far, you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33637875/edit) your question to add more information.

Comment: Just added the code! :)

Comment: Once you have the URL, you can simply do `Process.Start("http://icanhazip.com")` (in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace) to launch that URL in the default browser.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out guys, i close to finding a solution! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a console app, you won't be able to click a link because the page won't be displayed. You could grab the links off the search results page but then how would you display the page after you navigate??? I don't guess I understand what the overall goal of your project is.

If all you want is to grab the links off the google search results page you can use the code below. It will grab the URLs of all of the search results on the page. You can then display how ever many of the links on the screen and then after the user chooses a link, navigate (something?) to the desired URL.

```
IWebElement searchInput = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib"));
searchInput.SendKeys(command);
searchInput.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
By linkLocator = By.CssSelector("cite._Rm");
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(linkLocator));
IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> links = Driver.FindElements(linkLocator);
foreach (IWebElement link in links)
{
    Console.WriteLine(link.Text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! The app compiles with no errors so far! What i want to do is this:  
After i get the links, i would like the app to ask the user: "Which link do you want me to click?"
and the user should say: "click on the first" or "second" or "third" etc
and then the app automatically goes to the selected link!
kinda like:
'console.Writeline("Which link do you want me to click?");'
'string choice = console.Readline();''
'choice.click();'
'//Where "click" is the url'

Comment: correction: "Where "choice" is the link (Won't let me edit the comment for some reason) Thanks again!

Comment: Your question is how to get the first five links from a google search and this answer answered that question. If you have additional questions, please post a new question. Thanks.

Comment: Got it, thanks again for the help, I appreciate it! :)